# Google-api-go-client: listing messages w/ label and fetching header fields

Tags: go, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-go-client

I want to list messages with a specific label.  So I used the [Go Quickstart code from google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/go) and set the scope to gmail.MailGoogleComScope.

Getting a list of all messages with label "INBOX" works fine using this code

```
    mes, err := srv.Users.Messages.List(user).LabelIds("INBOX").Do()
```

but when I replace "INBOX" with "TEST" I get the error:

> nable to retrieve Messages. googleapi: Error 400: Invalid label: TEST,
>   invalidArgument exit status 1

and there is a label with name TEST. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably TEST is reserved https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels#types_of_labels, read the note in blue at the bottom... If that's the case maybe, maybe not, changing the label to TESTING will work just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The label name and ID of "INBOX" are the same. But, there is a case to differ between the label name and label ID. You have 2 methods for retrieving message list of the label. Following scripts suppose the use of [Go Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/go) from google.

### 1. Check label IDs and retrieve message list

**Retrieve label names and IDs :**

```
mes, err := srv.Users.Labels.List(user).Do()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error: %v", err)
}
for _, e := range mes.Labels {
    fmt.Println(e.Name + ", " + e.Id)
}
```

**Retrieve message list using `labelID` :**

```
mes, err := srv.Users.Messages.List(user).LabelIds(labelID).Do()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error: %v", err)
}
for _, e := range mes.Messages {
    fmt.Println(e.Id)
}
```

### 2. Retrieve message list using "Q"

```
mes, err := srv.Users.Messages.List(user).Q("label:labelname").Do()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error: %v", err)
}
for _, e := range mes.Messages {
    fmt.Println(e.Id)
}
```

This can be directly retrieved a message list for the label name. Parameters of "Q" are the same to the Gmail search box.

**References :**

1. Users.messages: list https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list
2. Users.labels: list https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list